# Git - includeIf hasconfig:remote.*.url not working

Tags: git

I want to use two separate GitHub accounts on the same computer so I setup ssh keys for both of them. Both are working fine. I don't want to config my email and name each time I create a new repo so I looked around and found git's "includeIf" section.

I am using git version 2.37.3

These are my config files right now.

~/.gitconfig

```
[user]
    email = "home@example.com"
    name = "Home"

[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:git@github.com-Work:*/**"]
    email = "work@example.com"
    name = "Work"
```

~/.ssh/config

```
Host github.com-Home
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/Home

Host github.com-Work
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/Work
```

When I clone a repo like `git clone git@github.com-Home:Home/repo.git` and run `git config user.name` inside the repo, I get the expected output of `Home`

However, when I clone a repo for my work account like `git clone git@github.com-Work:Work/repo.git` and run `git config user.name` inside the repo, I get `Home` instead of `Work`. Running `git config remote.origin.url` returns `git@github.com-Work:Work/repo.git`

Any idea of why this isn't working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `includeIf...` statement only allows, as its name suggests, to include another *file* (as opposed to: a config section within the same file).

You would have to put your `email, name` parameters in a separate file, and point to that file using `path = ...` in your main config file.

---

quoting the relevant example from [`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_example):

```
; include only if a remote with the given URL exists (note
; that such a URL may be provided later in a file or in a
; file read after this file is read, as seen in this example)
[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:https://example.com/**"]
    path = foo.inc
```

The pattern `git@github.com-Work:*/**` should be enough.

Comment: I linked a new config file and it works great. Thank you.

Comment: re: The final comment about `git@github.com-Work:**` in the answer -- for future readers, it's not enough. It needs to be `git@github.com-Work:*/**` (see the other answer in this post).

Answer (score 12):

Of course, the first thing to change is what @LeGEC has already mentioned.

However, there is another additional detail that should be taken care of (which is already done in the question, but I'd like to emphasize it and since I can't comment, I'll post it as an answer for future reference).

The URL specified must have a glob pattern of `*/**` at the end. `**` won't be sufficient and thus you might find yourself in a situation where git will not include the additional configuration.

Example:

```
git@github.com-Work:*/**
```

instead of

```
git@github.com-Work:**
```

This was something I didn't know and thus I was wondering why it didn't work. For me the solution was the question!

Comment: I arrived at `*/**` for SSH urls by trial and error. `**/**` also worked. Weird how globs work for git, would be good to have a better reference for these rules.